# Why is the battery life so bad on my new PocketBook InkPad Color?

Tags: battery

I quite recently bought a brand new PocketBook InkPad Color, having read something about "a month per charge".

But now I've yet again recharged it because it was almost out of power after just 1-2 days. I'd say 48 hours tops.

Sure, I've used the light (on the lowest setting) when reading in the dark for a while, but not very long. And I've only opened various books in it -- not used any kind of CPU-intense game or something. (If such even exist.)

I must say that I'm baffled and disappointed by how quickly the battery is drained with such minimal use.

Whenever I don't use it, I press the button to make it go to sleep.

Is there something wrong with my unit? I frankly can't bear returning another item in my life, so I *hope* that this is normal. But it surprises me, because I thought that even smartphones had much better battery life than this, and they do much more advanced and energy-draining things. The whole point of an "e-reader" is that uses a special kind of screen to use minimal battery and near-zero battery unless you actively open a book or change pages, is it not?

I will say that I don't have any smartphone, and never have had one, so I don't really know how long they last, but I assume that you don't have to charge those every single day.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not *normal*. Most e-readers should easily work for a few weeks. If you already tried resetting your PocketBook, I don't think there's anything else you can do except for warranty repair :(

Side-note about smartphones: yes, most of them can work 1-2, or even 3 days when using it "normally"